# How to remove elements from array without using System.Collection or LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I've got a problem when "removing" elements from array in C#, but **without using System.Collection  and LINQ**.

for example:

I have a `Product` class which contains fields `p_name`, `p_number` and `is_useful` (this value is `true` by default);

I also have a `ShoppingCart` class which contains field `market_name`, `products_quantity` and `Products` (the type is `Product[]`, storing all products)

Suppose I've created four `Product` objects `p1`, `p2` , `p3`, `p4`, and then created one `ShoppingCart` object `sc` with a fixed length `Products[4]` ( `p1`, `p2`, `p3` & `p4` are stored it);

Then I set the `is_useful` value of `p2` to `false`, so `p2` in the `Products[4]` will become useless for the `ShoppingCart`, and it needs to be removed from `Products[4]`.

is it possible that remove `p2` from `Products[4]`, and the length of this array will be reduced to 3 (`Products[3]` with `p1`, `p3` & `p4` inside), and it still belongs to the `Shoppingcart` object `sc` (like when I use `sc.Products` to get the all products, it will refer to the new `Products[3]`)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a `List<Product>`?

Comment: Yeah...Collection and LINQ are not allowed to use, I know it would be easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb348051.aspx) static method:

- replace element you'd like to remove with the last one
- call `Array.Resize` with your array reference and length set to current length - 1

```
// let's say you'd like to remove the i-th element
//
// You don't have to move Products[i] to the last position,
// because it will be removed anyway.
sc.Products[i] = sc.Products[sc.Products.Length - 1];
// Call Array.Resize to change array size
Array.Resize(sc.Products, sc.Products.Length - 1);
```

Comment: You should note that `Array.Resize` allocates a new array, does not resize the old one. This matters when other references to the `Products` array exist: these would refer to the array with the "removed" element moved to the end, and the original size.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You're right. But I don't think you can do the same without allocating new array. If you need the reference to stay as it is, use `List<T>`

Comment: Absolutely, re-allocating is the only way to go here. It's just a good thing to let the OP know that there's no "magic" here :-)

Comment: You're missing `ref` keyword here and If Products is a property you can't do this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems like switch `p4`and `p2` and then cut `p2` off, so the resized array `Products[3]` will be the order `p1`,`p4`,`p3`. Is it also possible to keep the original order (if `p2` removed, the resized array will be the order `p1`,`p3`,`p4`)?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the way of top of my head:

1. setting the element to null (and moving it to end : optional), and handling the null value in you access code. (you can use a wrapper method/class for this too)
   adv: this doesn't involve in any object recreations, reallocation.
2. `Array.Resize()` : involves array reallocation, but if your array is short and the operation is very in-frequent you can live with this solution. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx)
3. Using Collection: Ideal for dynamic sized lists/arrays.